# Upload PDF form to server via submit in Acrobat

Tags: php, pdf

I created a pdf form using acrobat. The form has a submit button, and I would like to actually submit the entire form, and upload it to the server. Is there a way to do this? I am experienced with PHP, and other languages, but not so much with anything to do with PDF Forms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP handle a PDF form submitted as a complete PDF document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284640/can-php-handle-a-pdf-form-submitted-as-a-complete-pdf-document)

Comment: Sorry, but it is not. The $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] only shows the posted data. I am looking to actually take the submitted form and upload it to the server, NOT receive the posted data.

Comment: Also, I attempted to submit it to a php web page, but I receive an error on the PDF saying it is unable to process HTML/PHP pages.

Answer (score 1):

During form creation, when you select the submit action for your button, Acrobat shows a dialog which asks you for the URL to submit the form data to. This dialog allows you to also select how the form shall be submitted. (At least it's this way in my ancient Acrobat 9.5.)

If you want the whole form to be submitted, i.e. a complete PDF with filled-in form fields, select the option for the complete PDF document.

If you don't want to get the base document you already have, but merely want to retrieve the additions as incremental update, select the option for the FDF and check step-wise changes box. You can build the complete PDF from the original form and these incremental updates.

For some backgrounds see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21850285/1729265) to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836816/how-to-write-pdf-signature-to-mysql-database).